# Character Model Hair

Tags: game-engine, shaders, hair, unreal-engine

I am working on a mid-poly character for a third person shooter in Unreal Engine 4, however I'm running into difficulty with her hair[image]. So far I've been making basic hair cards, mainly just repeating strips I vary by hand to give a spiky appearance. However even with the Cycles principled hair shader, the hair definitely looks like a mess of triangles. Any suggestions?[image]

Comment: You have to add transparency to it with a node setup like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZCKX.jpg

Comment: Curves work great with hair. That might be able to fix the problem. Try using curves to do the hair. I've tried a few methods, but curves work the best for me.